# The method given() is undefined for the type PendingTransactionsTest

Tags: java, json, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I am conducting my first Acceptance Test case using Junit in Eclipse.  The code below is not complete because I'm still working on it.  I ran into this error, however, and I am not sure how to solve it.

Error Type: The method given() is undefined for the type

Code:

```
package bns.so.unitTest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import bns.so.models.PendingTransactionsRequestModel;
public class PendingTransactionsTest extends BaseUnitTest{

    Map<String, Object> mapBody = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private static PendingTransactionsRequestModel transModel = new PendingTransactionsRequestModel();
    private static final String countryID = "ZZ";
    private static final String accountID = "2";
    private static final String customerID = "3";
    private static final String startDate = "2016-10-31 00:00:00";
    private static final String endDate = "2016-12-07 00:00:00";
    private static final String startAmount = "123123";
    private static final String endAmount = "200000";
    private static final String sortOption = "asc";
    private static final String sortOrder = "desc";
    private static final String numRecords = "1";
    private static final String lastRecordKey = "0";
    private static final String transType = "FundsTransfer";


    @Test
    public void accountIdTest(){
        mapBody = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mapBody.put("accountID", PendingTransactionsTest.accountID);
        RestAssured.
        given().
        header("accountID", 2).
        contentType("application/json").
        body(mapBody).

    when().
        post("path").

    then().
        statusCode(200).
        //body("status.status", equals (0)).- doesn't work how do I reword this?
        body("status.reason", null);

}}
```

Comment: If you remove RestAssured from in front of given method what happens?

Comment: I tried that, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use below import statement:**

```html
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this import

```
static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
```

Also, replace `RestAssured.given()` with `given()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used "import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;" and declare the variable as
"io.restassured.response.Response res;"